# Partitioning: Shrink Ubuntu (extended), Expand Windows

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have backups up everything, but I'm still uneasy about the process and would like confirmation. I'd rather do this one time correctly.

I want to shrink **/dev/sda6/** by 200GB and reallocate it to **/dev/sda2**.

I boot a LiveCD and turn off LinuxSwap (locked otherwise). I've been reading that it is very hard to move "left" when partitioning and other AskUbuntu threads are confusing me. Do I need to resize **/dev/sda6** by 200GB "preceding" (rather than "following"), and then resize **/dev/sda4** by 200GB?

A little guidance would ease my nerves of messing everything up. Thank you ahead of time.

[image: Screenshot of GParted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the outline of what you should do:

1. Unmount the devices/partitions concerned;
2. Shrink the logical partition `/dev/sda6` by the amount you want i.e. 200 GB (right click the partition, select resize/move and drag the slider to right creating the unallocated space to the left of `sda6`), and then move `sda5` to right over the unallocated space so that the entire free space will lie to left of `sda5`;
3. Shrink the extended partition `/dev/sda4` creating free space immediately next to `sda3`;
4. Move `/dev/sda3` towards right so that the entire 200 GB unallocated space would now lie next to `/dev/sda2` (Note: moving `/boot` may result in boot failure, and in that case you'd *boot-repair* disk can be handy.);
5. Resize `/dev/sda2` to cover the unallocated space;
6. Apply all operations, and wait patiently till the tasks are completed!

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. Grub loaded and ChkDsk is ran when you boot into Windows. One thing: Had to move **sda6** and then **sda5** to the right before moving **sda4**.

Comment: Good to know the problem's solved.. and thanks for the feedback, forgot to mention you can't move extended partition itself but the logical partitions within and then you'd shrink..